# Adding a enumerated list as content control and binding data in MS docx

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, docx, openxml-sdk

I have a content control field as 1 of the items in a enumerated list. How can I add further items (unknown number of items) to the list so that the item number gets incremented?

For eg this is the MS Word formatted enumerated list:

a) A sentence item.

b) `<controlFieldItem>`

The binding to Content control is done first with Word Content toolkit, then I use CustomXMLPart to replace template xml with data.

If I insert data using XML binding to the content control () the item is there. But I would like to able to add more items and the numbering to increment.

I think if if insert newline/return characters after each item to add in that field then the field will just have a new line within the item rather than create a new item in the list.

I could not find any list based content control fields, do these exist? How would I achieve this? Is it possible with Open XML library? Already using asp.net library to replace custom XML.

Comment: If I use rich text content control field and enter a new line in that field then the new item is enumerated.

But if I bind a custom xml path to this control field with Word 2007 Content Control Toolkit then the field defaults to a plain text field.

In plain text field it is not possible to add new item with new line. It only allows paragraphs within a item. How can I make sure the rich text is intact when binding with custom xml?

Comment: Google "word docx repeat content control"

Comment: Alright I had a look at repeat control control to enter items in the list in a dynamic way. Seems like I would I need to manipulate the XML in a more complex way like how it has been done for the table from Mike Ormond's aspx app in ContentControlsRepeatingData.zip?

https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=55575e4806858584&id=55575E4806858584%2112853&ithint=folder,.zip&authkey=!ALcT4WmveEY-gUE

How can I do this for a numbered list?